# What is EU-US security shield certificate means in term of EU PHI compliance

Tags: hipaa, regulation

I'm facing a regulation issue. 
My servers are hosted on Google Cloud.

I see that Google is [HIPAA](https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/hipaa/) and [Privacy Shield](https://www.privacyshield.gov/participant?id=a2zt000000001L5AAI) approved.

If my database servers are hosted with Google
and I'm storing personal health information there, am I allowed to store European patient's data and still be compliant to the European regulations?

Comment: Several things in are play in your question: Privacy Shield, GDPR, and health regulations. Just by storing something somewhere, you won't magically be compliant. You need to satisfy all the regulation (which is changing with GDPR).

Comment: @schroeder thanks for the reply. If i'm storing it in a server at google. knowing that google is EU-US privacy shield complaint, doesn't make my data complaint ? at least in some aspects ?

Comment: the question you need to ask is "compliant with what?" I'm saying that you have a few different things you need to be compliant with, and they are not all solved with a storage location.